# Настройка интернета на iMac через wi-fi

Tags: wifi, роутер, маршрутизация

Имеется роутер Tp-link, который раздает инет трем устройствам:

1. нетбук с ubuntu на борту (192.168.0.5)
2. iPad (192.168.0.100)
3. iMac (192.168.0.8)

Проблема в следующем: через какое то время на маке пропадает инет, при этом соединение по wi-fi остается (помогает только переконнект). Остальные устройства работают инет не теряют.

Может кто то сталкивался с похожей проблемой и помнит ссылки на возможные решения?

Comment: слушай, точно такая же проблема появилась и у меня пару дней назад, ничего специфичного не делал - не обновлял, не устанавливал - у тебя решилось?

Comment: Советуют канал поменять (немного поменяет частоту вещания, если не ошибаюсь). Вероятная причина: сейчас активно втыкают инет везде по wifi и у всех точек излучение на максимум. Я заметил активность пропадания совпадает с появлением новых сеток. Похоже как только соседи втыкают роутер в сеть и он начинает вещать - мой мак путается). Я пока не могу проверить это потому, что потерял пароль от инета и от роутера (перезагружу роутер чтобы поменять настройки - моему инету придет конец). Отпишись по случаю, как вышло!

Comment: А отчего путается именно мак, и больше никто? Советую погуглить  насчёт новых прошивок роутера (возможно, не родных). Мне, на Асусе(роутере) - помогло в аналогичной ситуации.

Comment: канал был выставлен на 3 вернул на авто - пока слежу. рутер - капсула с последней прошивкой

Comment: @areshin, так и хочу сделать (openwrt для моего tp-link есть) - только все руки не доходят. Рад, что моя догадка оправдала себя (меня это еще больше подстегнет к перенастройке своего роутера). На счет причин - увы, незнаю. Однозначно могу сказать, что я перепробовал все настройки на маке, чтобы решить эту проблему.

Comment: Последнее время Маки меня совершенно выводят из себя. Мои пользюки страдают (а некоторым еще хрен докажешь, что эпл - это не всегда приятно). Да и с iMac"ами дела не лучше, особенно новыми. Общение с поддержкой результатов не дает, так как они уверены, что эпл - это панацея, а cisco - галимый отстой. При том, что у пользователей PC проблем вообще не наблюдается ни с TP-Link ни с cisco. Найти проблему пока тоже не смог, решение - иногда помогает вручную прописать сеть (именно WiFi), иногда удалить сеть и заново подключиться.

Comment: смена канала пока помогает )) дело точно не в прошивке

Comment: @Dex, моя жена тоже бесится от этого мака и просит установить на нем винду!) Я пока держу оборону и ссылаюсь на то, что смогу его привести в человеческий вид!  Лично меня пока бесит невозможность установки многих игр

Comment: Попробую на досуге - уже поднадоело делать реконект.

Comment: неделя - полет нормальный :-)

Comment: @org, винда на маке - это еще то извращенство. Вы же покупали мак, а в нем все идет вместе и эпл обязалась поддерживать тоже все его компоненты, включая ОС. Так что этот вопрос бы даже не обсуждался, нафига его тогда покупать?